Field $K$ with char $0$ such that $K^\times$ is the disjoint union of $K^{\times2}$ and $-K^{\times2}$ but $K^{\times2}$ is not closed under addition
Motivation:
Today I encountered with the notion of Euclidean field: an ordered field $(K,\le)$ is called an Euclidean field if for every $x\in K$ such that $x\ge 0$, there exists $y\in K$ such that $x = y^2$.
I had the following observation:
Claim. For a field $K$, the following are equivalent:
$(1)$ There exists an order $\le$ on $K$ such that $(K,\le)$ is an Euclidean field;
$(2)$ $-1$ is not a square in $K$, and $K[x]/(x^2+1)$ is a quadratically close field, meaning that every element of $K[x]/(x^2+1)$ is a square;
$(3)$ $K^\times$ is the disjoint union of $K^{\times2}$ and $-K^{\times2}$, and $K^{\times2}$ is closed under addition, where $K^{\times2}=\{x^2:x\in K^\times\}$ and $-K^{\times2}=\{-x^2:x\in K^\times\}$.
Proof. $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$. For each $x\ge 0$, there is a unique $y\ge 0$ such that $y^2=x$, and we write $y=\sqrt{x}$. The square roots of $a+b{\rm i}\neq 0$, where $a,b\in K$ and ${\rm i}$ is a root to $x^2+1=0$, is explicitly given by
$$
\pm\left(x+\dfrac{b}{2x}{\rm i}\right),\quad x=\sqrt{\dfrac{a+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2}}
$$
if $a\ge 0$ and
$$
\pm\left(\dfrac{b}{2x}+x{\rm i}\right),\quad x=\sqrt{\dfrac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2}}
$$
if $a\le 0$.
$(2)\Rightarrow(3)$. For every $x\in K$, since $K({\rm i})$ is quadratically closed, there exists $a,b\in K$ such that $(a+b{\rm i})^2=x$, so $a^2-b^2=x$ and $2ab=0$. This implies that every element in $K$ is either a square or the negation of a square. Now prove that $K^{\times 2}$ is closed under addition. For $x,y\in K^\times$, pick $u,v\in K$, $(u,v)\neq(0,0)$ such that $(u+v{\rm i})^2 = x+y{\rm i}$, then $(u+v{\rm i})^2 = x-y{\rm i}$, so $x^2+y^2=(u^2+v^2)^2$, and $u^2+v^2\neq 0$ otherwise $-1$ is a square in $K$. This means that $x^2+y^2\in K^{\times 2}$.
$(3)\Rightarrow(1)$. The condition means that $K^{\times 2}\cup\{0\}$ is a positive cone, so it defines an order on $K$, which makes $K$ an Euclidean field.
In condition $(3)$, I was wondering that if $K^{\times2}$ being closed under addition is automatically deduced from $K^\times$ being the disjoint union of $K^{\times2}$ and $-K^{\times2}$. And it seems that it is not, at least in positive characteristics: Let $q\equiv 3\pmod 4$ be a prime power, then $-1$ is not a square in $\mathbb{F}_q$ (the field with $q$ elements), so $K^\times$ is the disjoint union of $K^{\times2}$ and $-K^{\times2}$ since $K^\times$ is cyclic. But of course $K^{\times2}$ is not closed under addition.

Question. How to construct a field $K$ with characteristic $0$ such that $K^\times$ is the disjoint union of $K^{\times2}$ and $-K^{\times2}$, but $K^{\times2}$ is not closed under addition?

(Note that $K^{\times2}$ being not closed under addition is equivalent to $x^2+y^2=-1$ has solutions in $K^\times$. This gives a non-constructive proof that $x^2+y^2=-1$ always have a solution in positive characteristics!)
